# Try to generate binary file with music21 library

Tags: python, pyinstaller, music21

music21 version
6.7.1

Problem summary
I try to generate a binary file with pyinstaller. And I get that error:

```
[17939] WARNING: file already exists but should not: /tmp/_MEIxs8i9Y/pyarrow/lib.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from NeckDisplayer import NeckDisplayer
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "NeckDisplayer.py", line 2, in <module>
    import music21.pitch
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "music21/__init__.py", line 192, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'music21' has no attribute 'alpha'
[17942] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

Steps to reproduce
Do a simple program and generate a binary file with pyinstaller:
`pyinstaller --onefile main.py`

More information
I try to do this on Ubuntu 18.04 with python 3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [fixed](https://github.com/cuthbertLab/music21/issues/881) in music21 v7.3.3.